# Decide given complexity of given function

Tags: asymptotics

I'm trying to determine correct notation for the given functions which are $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = (log(n))^{100}$. Moreover, I don't understand while calculating its complexity using limit because calculator shows that it goes infinity, so  f(n) is growing faster than g(n). But, I found vice versa. Could you explain me where I'm doing wrong? 
[image]

Comment: I don't quite get what your question is, but my guess is that you'd profit from looking at our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/599/reference-answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/846#846).

Comment: What do you mean by "determine correct notation for a function"?  Also, don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question harder to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  Note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that $\log$ is to the base 2.

Consider $n = 2^{1000}$. Then
$$
f(n) = 2^{1000}, \quad g(n) = (\log_2 2^{1000})^{100} = (1000)^{100} < (1024)^{100} = (2^{10})^{100} = 2^{1000}.
$$
If you increase $n$ even more, you will see an even more dramatic difference between $f(n)$ and $g(n)$. You just have to consider large enough $n$, perhaps too large for your calculator.

What this example shows that even though $f(n)$ grows faster than $g(n)$, for values of $n$ encountered in practice the situation is very different, with $g(n)$ being much larger than $f(n)$. This shows the limits of asymptotic analysis – it is a natural and useful mathematical notion, but it isn't always a good model for reality.

Comment: Thank you for your approach. We can find a constant and n0 to prove its omega, which is your approach; however, we can find a constant(1) and n0(4) to prove bigo as well. Can't we? So, shouldn't it be theta as a result?

Comment: No, you cannot. The function $f$ grows strictly faster than $g$.